# Can we pass GET variables in javascript url?

Tags: javascript, php

After form submission I want to redirect to another page where I need values from the Previous submitted form.

So in my redirect script I want to pass those values in GET

I am doing this :

```
<script>
var id = <?php echo $data['base_ini_id']."?&ext=".$data['ext']; ?>

window.location.replace("./edit_ini_custom/"+id);
</script>
```

OR Is there anything else with which I can do as required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get variables are (always) passed through the URL. So basically you should use:

```
var redirectUrl = "yourUrlWithVariables";
window.location.replcae(redirectUrl);
```

Now depending on the format of your target URL, the way you compose the target URL. Here are some common examples:
Format 1: baseUrl.com/page?paramName1=paramValue1&paramName2=paramValue2

```
var baseId = '<?=$data['base_ini_id'];?>';
var extId = '<?=$data['ext'];?>';
var baseUrl = "baseUrl.com/edit_ini_custom?base_ini_id="+baseId+"&ext="+extId;
```

Format 2: baseUrl.com/page/paramValue

```
var extId = '<?=$data['ext'];?>';
var baseUrl = "baseUrl.com/edit_ini_custom/"+extId;
```

Format 3: baseUrl.com/page/paramName/paramValue

```
var extId = '<?=$data['ext'];?>';
var baseUrl = "baseUrl.com/edit_ini_custom/ext/"+extId;
```

Format 4: baseUrl.com/page/paramName1/paramValue1/paramName2/paramValue2

```
var baseId = '<?=$data['base_ini_id'];?>';
var extId = '<?=$data['ext'];?>';
var baseUrl = "baseUrl.com/edit_ini_custom/base_ini_id/"+baseId+"/ext/"+extId;
```

Note that this are only guidelines, and in any case after you parse and build the target URL, you must call window.location.replace(baseUrl). Other option is just use:
window.location = baseUrl;
but using this will add that redirection to the history allowing users to hit "back", which I'm not sure is something you'd like.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The form that's already submitted (in the previous page) cannot be accessed, as such, from the next page.

So, in short, the answer to your question is NO.

You need to implement in one of the ways:-

- Store the values in the user's session object (if you already have login implemented)
- Use a Http Cookie or Browser's localStorage to store the value
- Persist the value to the server and fetch in the subsequent page, as hidden variables.

Comment: @sarth thanks but i got an answer i can do this by passing it in PARAMETER like this: window.location.replace("./edit_ini_custom/"+id+"/"+<?php echo $data['ext']; ?>);

Answer (score 0):

You can do a PHP redirect by setting the header **Location**

```
header("Location: ".$data['base_ini_id']."?&ext=".$data['ext']);
```

This will be a convenient way i guess than the one you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Got an Answer:

```
<script>
var id = <?php echo $data['base_ini_id']; ?>

window.location.replace("./edit_ini_custom/"+id+"/"+<?php echo $data['ext']; ?>);
</script>
```

I can pass the PHP Variable as **PARAMETER** And On the Function Where I need it i Just Have to Do  :

```
public function edit_ini_custom($id,$ext)
{
   echo $ext;
   //code
}
```